# Why does SAS not give p-values for the fixed effects in the mixed model?

Tags: sas, mixed-models, p-value

I work with a mixed model to see the effects of variables. The code I use is:

```
proc mixed data=pb2;
class treat_a treat_b hoknr_ day;
model conc=treat_a|treat_b hoknr_/outp=residuals1 residual;
repeated day/subject=hoknr_(treat_a treat_b)type=vc;
run;
```

The outcome has no p-values for treat_a, treat_b or treat_a|treat_b but it does for hoknr_. I excluded the repeated statement, I simplified the model, I changed class but still I got no p-values for all of my fixed effects. I have used this model before and it worked, now I fitted it to this dataset and it this not fully function.

**Edit1**
The table of Type 3 Tests of Fixed Effects shows like this:
[Type 3 Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZKXx.jpg).
The treatments could be non-estimable (treat_a is yes or no, likewise for treat_b). I have changed yes/no to 0 or 1, did not change the Type 3 Table. I have worked before with treatments being expressed in words what did not result in a table like this.

**Edit2** When solution is added to the model statement, this is the result: [Solution for Fixed effects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEfNX.png).

What is wrong with this model that it does not show p-values for all fixed effects?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to specify the type of test that you want with the `htype=` option. It sounds like one of those procs where someone didn't program the function initially, and it was kind of an afterthought late in development (not unlike the `showpvalues` option in `proc glmselect`; to this day I think that's the weirdest option in a regression proc).

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect015.htm#statug.mixed.mixedmodelhtype

> **Type 3 Tests of Fixed Effects**
>
> You can use the HTYPE= option in the MODEL statement to obtain tables
> of Type 1 (sequential) tests and Type 2 (adjusted) tests in addition
> to or instead of the table of Type 3 (partial) tests.
>
> The ODS table names are "Tests1" for the Type 1 tests, "Tests2" for the Type 2 tests, and "Tests3" for the Type 3 tests.

Or, it could be that some of your fixed effects are not estimable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added an edit to the question based on your answer.

Comment: Is your model not full-rank? i.e., are there more design columns than degrees of freedom for your fixed effects? Try using the `solution` option in your model statement and show us what you get.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of causing the 0 in your result is your treat_a and treat_b are categorical variables. And treat_a = 1 and treat_b = 1 are reference levels. So you are missing p values in your solution table. In your interaction terms, there won't have p values if the terms include treat_a=1 or treat_b=1.